# How to assign random codes to columns to determine sort order?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, analytics

**Question:** How can I assign a code such as **CC=1** and **WP=2** and make that part of the the query to get desired results? If there are multiple transactions on the same transaction date then apply the business rule.

Here's my query on **Oracle 11g**

```
select tid, 
       cycle,
       apply_no, 
       seq_no, 
       trans_date, 
       trans_type,
       priority
from ( select tid, 
              cycle,
               apply_no, 
               seq_no, 
               trans_date, 
                trans_type,
                rank() over (partition by tid,
                                 order by trans_date desc,seq_no desc) priority
from transactions where tid=1
```

**Current Results**

```
TID  cycle    apply_no  seq_no trans_date   trans_type  priority
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    201420    2        2       27-NOV-12   WP          1
1    201320    1        1       27-NOV-12   CC          2
1    201420    2        1       16-OCT-12   CC          3
```

**Desired Results**

```
TID  cycle     apply_no seq_no trans_date trans_type  priority
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    201420    2        2      27-NOV-12  CC          1
1    201320    1        1      27-NOV-12  WP          2
1    201420    2        1      16-OCT-12  CC          3
```

**Reason:** Business rules state CC takes priority over WP (not because CC sorts before WP)
if trans_date is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your trans_type order is actually alphabetical, you could just add that to your order by in the rank function.  However, to be more clear I would use a decode.. something like:

```
with transactions as
(
    select 1 tid, 201420 cycle, 2 apply_no, 2 seq_no, to_date('27-NOV-12','DD-MON-YY') trans_date, 'WP' trans_type from dual union all
    select 1 tid, 201320 cycle, 1 apply_no, 1 seq_no, to_date('27-NOV-12','DD-MON-YY') trans_date, 'CC' trans_type from dual union all
    select 1 tid, 201420 cycle, 2 apply_no, 1 seq_no, to_date('16-OCT-12','DD-MON-YY') trans_date, 'CC' trans_type from dual
)
select tid, 
       cycle,
       apply_no, 
       seq_no, 
       trans_date, 
       trans_type,
       priority
from ( select tid, 
              cycle,
               apply_no, 
               seq_no, 
               trans_date, 
                trans_type,
                rank() over (partition by tid
                                 order by trans_date desc,decode(trans_type,'CC',1,'WP',2,3),seq_no desc) priority
from transactions where tid=1 );
```

Which produces:

```
       TID      CYCLE   APPLY_NO     SEQ_NO TRANS_DATE  TRANS_TYPE   PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1     201320          1          1 27-NOV-2012 CC                  1
         1     201420          2          2 27-NOV-2012 WP                  2
         1     201420          2          1 16-OCT-2012 CC                  3
```

Comment: Craig, Yes I'll need to use the decode b/c the codes are arbitrary. It was just happenstance that they sorted alphabetically.